# KVM Switch - Image Quality

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi, vga, kvm-switch

Does a KVM Switch causes loss of image quality?

I want to install one but thinking if this will effect the quality of the image (colors/etc), displayed on the screens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have to say **yes**.  I have a 2-port KVM for two boxes I have at home, and the image quality is perceptibly different when I'm using the KVM with that monitor vs. when I'm not.  Mind you, I am using a cheap KVM, and with VGA cables, i.e. **analog signal**.

On the other hand, I expect that if you had a good KVM and were using DVI-D or HDMI cables instead, each of which sends a **digital signal**, then you shouldn't notice any degradation of the picture quality.

Comment: I'm suggesting that if you don't want to lose image quality, use DVI-D or HDMI as opposed to an old VGA-based KVM.

Comment: By the way, in my case, what I notice is that text and edges aren't as sharp in the middle of the screen when I go through the KVM.  Colors look fine; it's a sharpness issue for me.  But your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have the same issue with the sharpness. Why the vga adapter switch do change the sharpness, maybe because it's an electronic-switch to compare it with the old mechanical-switches ?